# List all distinct values of column and their count

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column with different text values. How can I get a list of all the unique values and the count of the appearance of them in the column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is to use `GROUP BY`

```
select text_column, count(*) from text_table group by text_column
```

more info - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column_name
     , COUNT(*)
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY column_name
;
```